# Hexadecimal in Android

Tags: android

I've been working with Hex Color codes in android lately. I have an application that uses a shared preference to save the hex value. I was looking in the shared preference save file and I noticed that instead of saving it as 0xFFFFFFFF, it saves it as -263173. Why does it do it this way. It's not causing any problems, and it pulls it and uses it just fine, but it's somewhat confusing to me when I'm trying to alter values in the file myself, and I want to understand why it's doing it this way. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not 0xFFFBFBFB that is getting stored as -263173? As Pascal has answered any hex number with the sign bit set will be a negative integer and 0xFFFBFBFB equates to -263173. 0xFFFFFFFF equals -1

Comment: You're right. It wasn't a perfect 0xFFFFFFFF I had set. Human error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color is stored like a simple signed Int, the first bit is 1 and make a negative value if you edit them directly. You should read it like a bits to get the right value.